Xdebug: Is it possible to freeze the call stack in Visual Studio Code?
I work with a php app that opens a lot of threads. This means that when I use xdebug I can't look at the call stack because it will refresh when a new thread opens, like this:
https://ibb.co/pf42Qy0
Is there any way to freeze the call stack, or to tell xdebug to stop catching threads on break?
Could not find a setting to stop this from happening.

I know it's not very clean but couldn't you test a global variable and try something like: if (global_first_thread==true) { xdebug_break(); global_first_thread = false;}

Thing is that "xdebug_break" will create a breakpoint and stop, but it won't stop new threads from coming in.

PHP doesn't really support threading out of the box. But the easiest way would be to turn off "listening for debug connections" in your IDE.
Every connection and debugging session that already exists will continue, with new ones not being established.

I'm not using out-of-the-box php, the support or lack thereof is not the issue. The problem is with the panel being constantly updated, which does not allow me to navigate the stack for the current thread. Turning off listening turns of the debugger altogether.
